# How to use user-systemctl as root?

Tags: linux, debian, systemd, users

I want to start a user service from my root shell without logging into the users shell.

I have tried the following command, but it fails:

```
#> su - username -c "systemctl --user"
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

How do I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2):

The following command seems to work, but looks rather unpleasant.

```
su - username --shell=/bin/sh -c 'export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u); systemctl --user'
```

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me:

```
runuser -u USER -- systemctl --user start USER.SERVICE
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a simple

```
# systemctl start servicename@username
```

e.g

```
# systemctl start tmux@e
```

for starting up my own global systemd-managed tmux session.

Answer (score 0):

Putting all parts of the other answers together (and using the recommended `runuser` instead of `su`) this works on current Debian/Ubuntu:

```bash
runuser username -c 'env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=$(id -u) systemctl --user'
```